# Upgrading to 16.04 LTS results in read only file system and can not start desktop

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, read-only

When upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS, the process asked me to run:

```
dpkg --continue -a
```

and the command failed, and some time later the upgrade process exits. I checked the 'About Ubuntu', it shows it is 16.04 LTS. Then I manually restart the system, and then I can't see the desktop again. After rebooting, it takes me to a terminal mode, when I tried to run `sudo dpkg --continue -a` again, it says the file system is read only. The following is the screenshot of the screen after rebooting ubuntu after upgrading to 16.04 LTS:

[image]

And below is the video captured during the start process:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuehCZIHNdI

During the process, we can see that the desktop is shown and closed immediately, not sure what the reason is.

Comment: are you root user?

Comment: I use sudo to run the command, it fails too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I looking for a solution to this issue, I using next workaround:
In terminal after these read-only errors:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then system load unity. However, this procedure needs to be used  after every reboot

UPDATE: You also can check the /etc/fstab file. In my case there was issue in incorrect filesystem mounting record. I found it when run fsck command:

```
sudo fsck
```

It return me line like this:

```
fsck: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 9 -- ignore
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, after using the remount command, I am able to start the windows with the 'sudo lightdm' command.

The next step is to find the root cause and fix it, so that we don't  remount it for every reboot.

Comment: Finally I've fixed the issue. I described it in UPDATE part of answer. The error in fstab file was a really tricky: there was a unexpected space symbol in **option** part of mounting record. So, I advice you to  check it too.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, my fsck works normally, no error in the output. I decide to reinstall ubuntu LTS 16.04 because it is slow after running the 14.04 version for two years.

Answer (score 3):

Here was what worked for me

Firstly, run `sudo su`

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

At this point you can run `exit` to leave the superuser mode.

Then I changed my swap file by running `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda1    /       ext4    rw,noatime,data=ordered    0   1
```

And finally I restarted my server

```
sudo reboot
```